# SQL Server Express version on windows 8.1

Tags: sql-server-2014-express

I am running windows 8.1. Which version of SQL Server Express edition should I download from following :

- SQL Server 2014 LocalDB Express 32bit
- SQL Server 2014 LocalDB Express 64 Bit
- SQL Server 2014 Express 32 Bit
- SQL Server 2014 Express 64 Bit
- SQL Server 2014 Express with Tools 32 Bit
- SQL Server 2014 Express with Tools 64 Bit
- SQL Server 2014 Management Studio Express 32 Bit
- SQL Server 2014 Management Studio Express 64 Bit
- SQL Server 2014 Express with Advanced Services 32 Bit
- SQL Server 2014 Express with Advanced Services 64 Bit

Answer (score 4):

Well, depends on what you **want**:

- 32- vs. 64-bit - your choice
- SQL Server 2014 LocalDB Express - LocalDB developer database - can be useful for EF code-first stuff
- SQL Server 2014 Express - this is **just the bare-bones engine** - no tools
- SQL Server 2014 Express with Tools - this is the engine **with** the management tools
- SQL Server 2014 Management Studio Express - this is **just** the management tools (**NO** engine!)
- SQL Server 2014 Express with Advanced Services - this is the version with Integration services, Reporting Services etc.

I would typically recommend the **with Tools** version - can't be without a Management Studio myself. Hardly ever needs the Integration and Reporting Services if I'm doing something with an Express edition.

If you need just the engine for a server install - grab the bare-bones engine - that's enough.